# Index was out of range

Tags: c#

I am getting this error...

> *Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
>   Parameter name: `index`.*

in the code at the indicated position.

```
List<int>[] tetangga = new List<int>[this.observasi];
for (int i = 0; i < this.observasi; i++) 
{
    tetangga[i] = new List<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < this.observasi; j++) 
    {
        if (tableWeight[i, j] > 0) 
        {
            tetangga[i].Add(j);
        }
    }
}

this.dataTable.ColumnCount = 2;
this.dataTable.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "REGION";
this.dataTable.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "REGION NEIGHBOR";
this.dataTable.Columns[1].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
this.dataTable.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
this.dataTable.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

int jlhRow = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < this.observasi; i++)
{
    jlhRow = jlhRow + tetangga[i].Count;
}
this.dataTable.RowCount = jlhRow;

int row = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < this.observasi; k++)
{
    this.dataTable[0, row].Value = this.nameRegion[k];  // <-- error occurs here
    for (int l = 0; l < tetangga[k].Count; l++)
    {
        this.dataTable[1, row].Value = this.nameRegion[tetangga[k][l]];
        row++;
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: What is `this.nameRegion`? Looks suspicious.

Comment: Kindly Please post full Stack Trace, Also index out of range is error occur because of he index you are going to access in array which is more then the given allocated size of array.

Comment: Breakpoint usage will help you. Try to put breakpoint into loop with exception and add watch on index, array and data.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is here

```
    for (int j = 0; j < this.observasi; j++) 
    {
        if (tableWeight[i, j] > 0) 
        {
            tetangga[i].Add(j);
        }
    }
```

How do we know what the 2nd dimension of tableWeight is?  I expect it does not go up to this.observasi.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point at the start of your loop, before the line:

```
this.dataTable[0, row].Value = this.nameRegion[k];
```

Examine `dataTable` and `nameRegion` in the debugger and you may answer your own question. It's likely that the collections do not contain elements at the indexes you are specifying.